# Lim of $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm working in this exercise:

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2n}.$$

I'm thinking about partitions and seeing this like an integral but I don't know which limits of integration should I use, maybe $0$ to $1$ since it's kinda close. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about viewing the sum as $\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+1/n}+ \frac{1}{1+2/n} + \cdots\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  your sum is the difference of two [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), $H_{2n}-H_n$